# How do I modify a node that contains a span?

Tags: javascript, html, range, nodes, contenteditable

I think my problem is simple, I tried the solution on https://developer.mozilla.org and other sites but nothing ...

```
//orignial value of selection: '<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Hello world</span>'

var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
content = range.extractContents(),
span = document.createElement('SPAN');
span.style.color = c[1];
span.appendChild(content);
range.insertNode(span);

//the result now is '<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"><span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Hello world</span></span>'
```

The problem is the result, i want see:

```
'<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">Hello world</span>'
instead of
'<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"><span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Hello world</span></span>'
```

All text is part of contenteditable div.

UPDATE:

I understand what I have to do, but I can not do it:
There is a moment, after var left = range.extractContents (), where I find myself with a span element that does not contain anything.
At that time I only see an empty span:  .
Now before you do span.appendChild (content); I need to destroy the old container.
How do I destroy this empty span?

Comment: does removing 'span.appendChild(content);' achieve what your wanting?

Comment: I know this may be completely unrelated but it's great to see a developer who uses Vanilla JS without libraries. Now, as for the question, have you tried removing the span and inserting the `content` directly to the `range`..?

Comment: 'span.appendChild (content)' is an important part of the code: because 'content = range.extractContents ()' removes the selected content, it is as if all the operation was a size and paste.

Comment: check my edit pls

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding this is the result you want:

```
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">Hello world</span>
```

Since this is the case, you shouldn't be creating a new span element and appending it inside of the range

As a matter of fact this problem can be solved quite easily, all you have to do is directly insert the content into the range element, like this:

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
content = range.extractContents();
range.insertNode(content);
```

You could even simplify it it, like this:

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
range.insertNode(range.extractContents());
```

Comment: I did not understand how you would get the new attribute of the element in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here

```
span.appendChild(content);
```

You are appending the content to your span twice.  Instead, just insert it directly into range.  Like so:

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
content = range.extractContents(),
span = document.createElement('SPAN');
span.style.color = c[1];
range.insertNode(span);
```

Comment: Sorry but don't work, because the result of this operation is empty, because at the end of the operation, it deletes all selected content.

Comment: The result of this operation is <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"></span> instead of <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">Hello world</span>

Answer (score 1):

By doing simply `range.insertNode(span);`
basically you are trying to insert an element inside the span element you already selected that's why you get:

```
'<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"><span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Hello world</span></span>'
```

instead of

```
 '<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">Hello world</span>'
```

Here is what I came up with. This will solve your case. It's not rocket science but it still works on what you want to achieve:

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
content = range.extractContents(),
span = document.createElement('SPAN');
span.style.color = c[1];
span.appendChild(content);
range.insertNode(span);
var abc = span.cloneNode(true);
span.parentElement.parentElement.insertBefore(abc, span.parentElement);
span.parentNode.remove();
```